# Run PowerShell command in batch

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I use the following PowerShell command to run a Perl command (pp):

```
pp --% -u -x -g --link openssl.exe --link libpng16-16_.dll -o D:\Dati\file.exe -F Bleach="^(AT_|DB_)" "G:\Scripts work\script.pl"
```

Copy and Paste it in PowerShell, and it works like a charme. Now I want to run the same from a bat file. I tried:

```
set CMD_LINE_ARGS="%*"
powershell -Command "{pp --% -u -x -g --link openssl.exe --link libpng16-16_.dll -o D:\Dati\file.exe -F Bleach="^(AT_^|DB_)" "G:\Scripts work\script.pl"}"
```

I tried to escape the pipe "|" with `.
My bat is run, no errors, but my script is not lunched. Any idea?

Comment: You will need to escape those inner quotes in batch. `"^(AT_^|DB_)" "G:\Scripts work\script.pl"` --> `\"^(AT_^|DB_)\" \"G:\Scripts work\script.pl\"`. If any of those `^` are literal, you will need to escape them as well. For example, if the first `^` needs to be passed to PowerShell, then you need to escape it: `"^(AT_^|DB_)" "G:\Scripts work\script.pl"` --> `\"^^(AT_^|DB_)\" \"G:\Scripts work\script.pl\"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape special CMD characters in batch in order for them to parsed by PowerShell.exe. Some characters include `"`,`^`. Inner double quotes can be double quoted or escaped with a backslash. Command characters need to be escaped with `^`.

```
powershell.exe -Command "{pp --% -u -x -g --link openssl.exe --link libpng16-16_.dll -o D:\Dati\file.exe -F Bleach=\"^^(AT_^|DB_)\" \"G:\Scripts work\script.pl\"}"
```